# How i can unsubscribe to a 'changefeed' in RethinkDB?

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe, rethinkdb

I know that i can subscribe for listen the changes on a table doing this

```
r.table('users').changes().run(conn, function(err, cursor) {
  cursor.each(console.log);
});
```

But, how i can stop to listen this changes? How i can unsubscribe for this changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `cursor.close()`, (or you can do `conn.close()`)

From the [docs for cursor.close](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/close-cursor/):

> r. Closing a cursor cancels the corresponding query and frees the memory associated with the open request.

Additionally, closing the connection itself will automatically close all cursors associated with a connection. In other words, if you're closing connections properly, you usually won't need to explicitly close your cursors.

From the [connection.close docs:](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/close/)

> Closing a connection normally waits until all outstanding requests have finished and then frees any open resources associated with the connection. By passing false to the noreply_wait optional argument, the connection will be closed immediately, possibly aborting any outstanding noreply writes.

Comment: I'm not sure what other information would be helpful here. The question asked how to unsubscribe from a changefeed, with example code. I explained how to do that using his variable names, implicitly referring to his snippet.

Comment: Fair enough, I've added links to the docs and copied in relevant snippets

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I asked this because i'm trying to create an alert system in my application, so when a user create an alert, i will subscribe him to a changefeed, but the user can remove this alert too, so i need a way to unsubscribe this user of this feed. And the create and remove methods are endpoints of my API. Have some idea of how i can do that?

Comment: Store your cursor somewhere in your app state, and close it when the user calls the remove() method.

Comment: So, i can do that,

`var myCursor;
r.table('users').changes().run(conn, function(err, cursor) {
  myCursor = cursor;
});
`
And then just call: myCursor.close();

This works?

Comment: Exactly, you just need to store your cursor somewhere

Comment: But this is not a good solution, because if my application is down, i will lost the variable values. And when my application is back, how i can get the values of all cursors again?

Comment: In rethinkdb 2.2, we're adding the ability to have persistent changefeeds that will survive a lost connection and keep all of your events. Right now there's no way around this if the application goes down

Comment: I should mention, however, that usually this isn't a huge problem. You can just refetch the current value from the server, and start a new changefeed. Persisting across restarts only matters if you cannot afford to miss *any* intermediate events, or if refetching results from scratch would be too expensive (say you have thousands of results)